# Rambam's Mussar to Son

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, machlokes

Where precisely does the Rambam give mussar to his son about avoiding conflict? [This](http://klalperspectives.org/rabbi-moshe-hauer-4/) article from Klal Perspectives quotes Kisvei HaRambam, Mussar l’bno Rav Avraham saying

> Do not sully yourself with machlokes (strife) that destroys the body,
>   the soul and property, leaving nothing.  I have seen the bright
>   blackened, leaders diminished, families broken, princes demoted from
>   their positions, large cities weakened, groups disbanded, pious people
>   lost, the trustworthy erased [and] honored people shamed and disgraced
>   – all as a result of strife. Prophets prophesized, wise men shared
>   their wisdom and philosophers explored and elaborated on the evils of
>   strife, and they all could not truly capture the extent of it. Thus, I
>   urge you to despise it and distance yourself from it and from all
>   those who consider themselves its friends and supporters.

but where can I find that particular text?

Comment: I believe [this](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=43026#p=222&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=0) is the letter attributed to the Rambam, addressed to his son. Although I can't seem to find the paragraph you quote. Note that many scholars believe this letter to be a forgery.

Answer (score 1):

An English translation of this letter (slightly different from the one you cite) was published by Leon Stitskin in *Tradition* 9:4 (Spring 1968) under the title ["The Last Will and Testament of Maimonides"](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%209/No.%204/Moses%20Maimonides%20The%20Last.pdf). It begins on page 80, with the relevant part beginning five lines from the bottom on page 86:

> Do not contaminate, moreover, your souls with controversies
>   which consume the body, the soul and property – what else is
>   then left? I have seen the way white is turned black, the refined
>   vulgarized, families torn asunder, rulers removed from their
>   high positions, big cities destroyed, communities deserted, the pious perverted, the faithful spoiled, the honorable disparaged
>   and despised – all because of controversy. The prophets prophesied against it; the wise men poured out their wisdom and
>   the philosophers probed its rationale and underscored the evil
>   of quarrelsomeness, but to no avail. Therefore, resolve in your
>   heart to detest and run away from acrimony and dissassociate
>   yourselves from its companions, well-wishers and neighbors. Remain aloof and stay at a distance even from quarreling relatives
>   lest you suffer from their aberrations.

Note that [R. Yitzchak Sheilat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Sheilat) in Igrot HaRambam classifies this letter in the category of "definite forgeries", and advances a number of arguments in explanation.